# setState hook in Promise.all only updates the last element of the component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/quant_eaglet/pen/OJWKVep) and the code below.

The state of my component is an array of todos that is created and updated with a `useState` hook. Each todo can be edited and saved with its own Save button that calls a `saveTodo` async function.

I'm trying to implement a Save All button which would the call the saveTodo function for each todo in a `Promise.all` - see `handleOnSaveAllClicked` below

Right now only the last todo is updated. Any clue to update them all ?

Thank you.

```
async function stall(stallTime = 3000) {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, stallTime));
}

const Todo = ({ todo, onFormChanged }) => {
  const onChange = (key) => {
    return (e) => onFormChanged(todo.id, { [key]: e.target.value });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        <p>Name</p>
      </label>
      <input type="text" value={todo.name} onChange={onChange("name")} />
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const initDate = new Date()
  const initialTodos = [
    { id: 1, name: "Todo 1", time: initDate},
    { id: 2, name: "Todo 2", time: initDate }
  ];

  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState(initialTodos);

  const saveTodo = async (todo) => {
    //simulate async http call
    await stall(1000)

    const newTodo = { ...todo, ...{ time: new Date() } };
    setTodos(todos.map((t) => (t.id === newTodo.id ? newTodo : t)));
  };
  
  const handleOnSaveAllClicked = async () => {
    await Promise.all(todos.map(t => saveTodo(t)))
  }
  
  const handleOnSaveClicked = async (id) => {
    const todo = todos.find((t) => t.id === id);
    await saveTodo(todo)
  };
  
  const handleFormChange = (id, data) => {
    const todo = todos.find((t) => t.id === id);
    const newTodo = { ...todo, ...data };
    setTodos(todos.map((t) => (t.id === id ? newTodo : t)));
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  handleOnSaveAllClicked();
                }}
        >Save All</button>
      {todos.map((t) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
              <p>{t.name} lasted saved on {t.time.toLocaleString()}</p>
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  handleOnSaveClicked(t.id);
                }}
              >
                Save
              </button>
              <Todo todo={t} key={t.id} onFormChanged={handleFormChange} />
            </form>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: You are capturing the todos by closure so saveTodo (even the last one) gets a reference to the `todos` before the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the `todos` that existed when the function was created, not the most recent `todos`. So you end up overwriting any changes that have been made in the meantime. To use the most recent one, use the function version of setTodos:

```
setTodos(prev => prev.map((t) => (t.id === newTodo.id ? newTodo : t)));
```

Comment: Interesting, I had never seen this function version. Why is this not the default? It would prevent all stale state issues ? Thank you